# In Indesign CC 2015 how can i edit page numbers

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am unable to edit page number which appears at the bottom.

The screenshot is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this comes from the master, so you will need to Override All Master Pages Items from the Pages palette.

Comment: If it answered your question, please flag the answer as correct.